# Did I really just put a string data type into an IEnumerable<int>

Tags: c#, linq, casting

Ok, this is a little weird. Ignore what I am trying to do, and look at the result of what happens in this situation.

**The Code:**

```
static string rawNumbers="1,4,6,20,21,22,30,34";
static IEnumerable<int> numbers = null;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    numbers = rawNumbers.Split(',').Cast<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count(); i++)
    {
        //do something
    }

}
```

**The Situation:**

The line `numbers = rawNumbers.Split(',').Cast<int>();` *appears* to work, and no exception is thrown. However, when I iterate over the collection, and InvalidCastException is thrown.

Now, drill down into the source and look at `CastIterator<TResult>`. This seems to be getting called at `for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count(); i++)`...specifically `numbers.Count()`

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> CastIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
    foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj; 
}
```

The error is happening on the cast, and when I look at the data in the `source` varaible it is a string[].

I would have thought that since the line where I call the cast to an int executed successfully everything was fine. What is going on behind the curtain? Is the string array really just being stored somewhere, and not being casted to T until it is called for? Lazy casting perhaps?

---

I know I cant do: (int)"42". My questions isn't how to make the cast work, but what is going on. Deferred execution of the cast? It seems weird the line where I call out `Cast<int>()` seems to work, but really doesn't.

Comment: As an aside I think deferred execution (or something similar) happens with MatchCollections in RegEx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As has been noted, 'Deferred Execution' is the issue here. Many LINQ operators do not cause your lambda code to actually execute until you iterate over the result variable.

One reason for this is to allow you to build up a complex series of operations that can be executed at one time, rather than as a string of separate operations. This can be a useful thing - but it also can be tricky if you aren't expecting it.

Answer (score 24):

A couple of things: first, you can't *cast* a `string` to an `int`.  You can parse a string and get a resulting integer.  But essentially you're trying to do this:

```
int x = (int)"32";
```

That's an exception.  **Second, the LINQ operators are deferred execution, so nothing actually happens until you attempt to iterate the result, that's when the real work starts happening.**

With deferred execution there is no checking on whether the operations you're requesting are valid or can be properly performed, it just sets up the operations and then attempts to perform then individually upon iteration.

Comment: I bolded the important part for you :)

Comment: Thanks, I notice he edited question and asked about the deferred execution; not sure if that was before or after my answer. :)

Comment: The bolded sentence is the only one that matters.

Answer (score 5):

The reason that `Cast` appears to work, is because the `IEnumerable` isn't enumerated when the method is called, but rather when you call `Count()`.  So, the call to `Cast()` really does nothing.  The code fails as soon as the Cast is actually evaluated.

Instead of trying to cast, just do a simple conversion.

```
numbers = rawNumbers.Split(',').Select(str => int.parse(str));
```

Comment: Yeah, finding a way to make the cast work isn't my problem. I am just curious as to what is going on that makes it look like it was fine, but it really wasn't

Comment: Because the .Cast() and other LINQ friends don't execute their operations at the time you call them, they create iterators that will perform the operation when they are enumerated.

Comment: @Joe, I added the reason to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you are not getting an error immediately at the `Cast<int>()` line is because remember this is just chaining up the sequence of operations. Only once you iterate over the collection will the conversions be executed.

`rawNumbers.Split(',')` happens right away, but the `Cast<int>()` is deferred computation.

If you added a ToList() or ToArray() on that line, it would have executed immediately.

Answer (score -1):

I may be wrong but I wonder if it has to do with casting between int and string. I always get errors when I forget you cannot cast against string using (int), rather you have to use int.Parse. It probably has something to do with that but this is just off the top of my head.

Comment: He's not asking why it isn't working, he's asking why the error only shows up when iterating over it which is happening because of deferred execution.

Comment: @BFree ; glad you commented on cdhowie and Mike Cheel to let them know what was 'wrong' with their answers. Whether it was you or not who did it, I think the downvote was probably a bit much, but I guess that gets the point across too (when coupled with your comment, that is)

Comment: That is a part of the reason, but the main reason why the .Cast<int>() seems to work properly, is that it is "lazy computed", if I may say so. Then, the call to the casting doesn't occur until the IEnumerable is evaluated, that is, when the `Count` property is accessed. Then, before the `Count` property can be evaluated, it performs the Cast, and throws because a string cannot be type casted to int.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, I'm the one that downvoted, and I always add a comment when I do so. I just feel that when there are questions like this where the point of the question is "WHY doesn't this work" it drives me nuts when people post solutions. That was NOT the intent of the question...

Comment: @BFree +1 for the general principle. Downvoting without commenting on why sometimes feels good, but is rarely helpful to the person getting the vote :)

Comment: @BFree At least I attempted to point out where the problem was, unlike you. At least post your own answer before you start trolling, ok? What else does 'What is going on behind the curtain?' mean? And the OPs edit wasn't there when I answered. Its people like you that make people not want to help anybody. I'm sure I am not alone on this.

Comment: @Mike Cheel : Don't take the down vote personally. It's only 2 rep points, and I know I've "lost" a good 10+ points early on until the point being made really hit me: sometimes the obvious 'problem' in a post is not the actual question being asked. This question was such a case: the asker knew what was wrong with the conversion attempt; he just did not know why it was not failing at the point in the code where the attempt was made.

Comment: @Andrew Barber I answered this post before the OP said the part about 'My questions isn't how to make the cast work'. So my point is that when I answered it I was answering the question. He didn't say the other part until after I had already given my answer. So while BFree may think by trolling people he is somehow making a difference, he is only making people not want to help out.

Comment: @Mike: Go back to the original version of the question: "I would have thought that since the line where I call the cast to an int executed successfully everything was fine." How do you NOT imply from that (and the rest of the ORIGINAL question which is too long to post in a comment) that the OP knew what the problem was, but was wondering WHY it was showing up in a different spot??? And spewing "troll" nonsense is for 5 year olds. Grow up.

Comment: @BFree I was looking at where he said 'However, when I iterate over the collection, and InvalidCastException is thrown.' When he said what you quoted 'I would have thought...', that indicated to to me that he realized that there was a problem with the casting. If you read the other posts that you didn't downvote you can see that other people were thinking the same thing as me. Also, forum nazi comes to mind more than troll actually. Flame away!